# Chartist: want to either click or hover on a bar chart to bring up tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, chartist.js

Using the chartist tooltip plugin on a bar chart, I implemented a tooltip that comes up when the mouse cursor hovers over a bar, displaying the value of the bar plus other information. This works great. However, I'd like for this to work similarly when the user taps or clicks the bar, for touch-screen devices that don't support a mouse.

Ideal behavior would be for the tooltip to disappear when the user lifts the finger from the screen, or releases the mouse-click, similar to a "momentary contact" physical button or switch. However, what happens with the current hover implementation is that the tooltip remains displayed until an empty area of the chart is tapped or clicked.

How do I make the tap or mouse-click "momentary contact" without sacrificing the hover behavior?

Comment: Can you please add the current progress you have so that we can use that as a starting point. Thanks.

Comment: All I've really done, besides pulling in the required scripts (chartist.js, chartist.css, chartist-plugin-tooltip.css, chartist-plug-in-tooltip.min.js) is to push the required object into the series to plot:

 let thingToPush = {
                        meta:(plotData.labels[newIndex]+'plotData.tag),
                        value:dp[plotData.tag]
                        };

   plotData.series[0].push(thingToPush);